# Statistical significance of pairwise correlations

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, statistical-significance, multiple-comparisons

I have two matrices of samples $A, shape(A) = n \times k$ and  $B, shape(A) = m \times k$. We can assume, that each row in $A$ and each row in $B$ is sampled from a Bernoulli distribution - the values are Boolean. (But each row may have different parameter for the distribution.)

In other words, I have $k$ samples and for each I observe random variables $A_1, ..., A_n, B_1, ..., B_m$ that each have some Bernoulli distribution.

Now I would like to determine if $A$ is correlated to $B$ on some significance level based on the correlation of each row in $A$ to each row in $B$. I have computed a matrix of correlations $C, shape(C) = n \times m$ where $C_{ij} = corr\_coef(A_i, B_j)$. When I visualize $C$, there are some obvious non-noise patterns, so I want to say - "Yay, it's correlated!" . But how should I do this rigorously? What statistic should I calculate to be able to say "Yay, it's correlated on significance level $\alpha$"? Do I need to do ANOVA or something like that? Is this an instance of multiple comparisons problem?